# Zero conditional sentence with "can"

Tags: conditional-constructions

The normal zero conditional sentence has this structure with either "if" or "when", and uses the present simple in both sides:

> A happens **if/when** B happens.

My question is, can I rewrite the sentence as follows with "can" if I want to indicate possibility?

> A **can** happen **if/when** B happens.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course.

You're expressing possibility *within* the confines of a particular condition. It's no different logically to a statement like *prostate cancer can occur in males*. It's only a possibility that it can occur, and that possibility can only occur in a specific set of the population. Even if you have to use 'if' or 'when', you're still describing the conditions in which the possibility may occur.

For example:

> Flooding may occur if it rains heavily.

This means that heavy rain *can* cause flooding, but it is only a possibility.

Comment: Thank you. My doubt comes from the fact that the zero conditional refers to something that happens with 100% certainty. However, when I add "can" to the sentence, this indicates that it is possible but not 100% certain. Isn't it somewhat contradictory and awkward?

Comment: @billeck Why is it contradictory? You're expressing possibility *within* the confines of a particular condition. It's no different logically to a statement like *prostate cancer can occur in males*. It's only a possibility that it can occur, and that possibility can only occur in a specific set of the population. Even if you have to use 'if' or 'when', you're still describing the conditions in which the possibility may occur.